# Firebase Storage 402 Error with Exoplayer

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, exoplayer

While using Exoplayer to stream a video file stored in Firebase Storage, sometimes I am getting this error

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
                 com.google.android.exoplayer2.k.r$e: Response code: 402
                     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.k.o.a(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
                     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.k.m.a(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
                     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.h.j$a.c(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:848)
                     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.k.s$b.run(Loader.java:317)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

After reporting this issue at Github [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4734), it says that I am getting a quota limit. I am not sure if that is the overall problem, could someone explain it to me what is exactly the problem or how quota works in Firebase Storage? I already read the documentation but still don't get it on how quota works, sorry I am not good in that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you already reach your daily quota. I also report this issue in Exoplayer repo before and they say that it has nothing to do with the media player but with the server that refuse to perform the task due to quota. In Philippines the refresh quota is 5pm onwards, and you'll see the error is gone and you can now read images and other media files in Firebase Storage.